# Worst Time Complexity for 2D Patten Matching

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching, time-complexity

What is the worst-time complexity for a 2D pattern matching using the brute-force algorithm?

I feel like it's O(m^2 * n^2) if haystack-size = n an needle-size = m (both are squares).

The way I got there is using a simple case scenario when m = 2 and n = 4. If we move horizontally across the row (matching the m x m characters in the haystack), we do m^2 string comparisons (n - 1) times. This we repeat for (n-1) times vertically. So, time = m^2 (n - 1) x (n - 1) = m^2 * n^2  - 2 * m^2 * n + m*2 = O(m^2 * n^2).

Is this analysis correct? Is it O(m^2 * n^2) or it should be O(m^2 * n^2  - 2 * m^2 * n + m*2)?

EDIT: I'm just comparing two matrices of strings or maybe something like two bit matrices. Example:

```
haystack = [["a", "b", "c", "d"],
            ["e", "f", "g", "h"],
            ["i", "j", "k", "l"],
            ["m", "n", "o", "p"]]
needle = [["j", "k"],
          ["n", "o"]]
```

Comment: What is "2D pattern matching using the brute-force algorithm"?

Comment: I'm just comparing two matrices of strings i.e. two multi-dimensional arrays of strings. Please see the edit above.

Comment: It seems that the haystack/needle could both be viewed as linear sequences; that is, just a normal "str in str" search with the slight difference that that the the haystack pointer is advanced in a different stride during a match attempt - e.g. instead of always by 1, it is 1,3(haystackwidth-1),1,3,.. But this doesn't change where the initial haystack/needle started inside the linear-ized sequences.

Comment: So are you suggesting that the time complexity will still be the same?

Comment: I would imagine it would be `O(n*m)` as per a native "str in str", where n and m refer to the number of *elements* in each matrix (not the dimensions of the matrices).

Comment: Wait, that can't be true. If we consider the above haystack (and needle) as just a long linear sequence, n_new = n^2 and m_new = m^2 and so time complexity = O(m_new * n_new) = O(m^2 * n^2)??

Comment: If `m` and `n` are the *dimensions* of each [square] matrix, then `elm_n = n^2` which leads back to the initial hypothesis of `O(m^2 * n^2)`.

Comment: What is rank? The haystack is m x m in size and the needle is n x n in size. m and n are their dimensions.

Comment: Poor terminology on my part. The "dimensions".

Comment: Yes m and n are the dimensions of the needle and haystack matrix (or arrays) respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match 2 2D arrays, to find all sub arrays, I think it's m*n*o*p (if the first array is m*n, and the second is o*p), to determine if any single char matches. Then I would say you need to multiply that by the dimensions of the larger array, as that would give you the sumber of possible sub-arrays. But there is undoubtedly a smarter approach to doing so than the brute force method, that starts with the smallest matching sub-array, and intelligently expands it, probably using dynamic programming. I would study substring matching algorithms, as this is analogous but in 2 dimensions.

Comment: I'm just comparing two matrices of strings i.e. two multi-dimensional arrays of strings. Please see the edit above.

Comment: You can match strings in linear time, just as you can match submatrices

Comment: Yeah but I'm thinking about the complexity for brute-force matching i.e. matching every possible sub-square in the haystack with the needle.

Comment: The 2D equivalent of the brute-force algorithm given here: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm). The 2D version takes O(mn) time.

Comment: @Jess That's not brute force

Comment: I know the link is to Rabin-Karp algorithm which is NOT a brute-force algorithm but under "Shifting substrings search and competing algorithms", a brute-force algorithm is given.

Comment: @Jess: Yes, the algorithm degrades to O(m^2 n^2) in the worst case (when there are lots of hash collisions)

Comment: @Jess But with high probability it runs in time O(nm). Although the 2D version of the algorithm is not a direct, straightforward adaption of the 1D version

Comment: Why would it run in O(nm)? It has to compare everything, doesn't it?

Comment: @Jess I'm talking about Rabin-Karp, which uses hashing to avoid just that

Comment: Sure, Karp-Rabin would be O(nm) but I was talking about just comparing strings without hashing at all.

Comment: Wait, if we adapt Karp-Rabin, shouldn't it be Theta(n^2) (on average) and still O(m^2 * n^2) on worst-case?

Comment: @Jess: It should be O(m^2 + n^2) on average and O(n^2 m^2) worst case. My mistake.